# How can I add same index of element of multiple arrays inside a huge array?

Tags: python

what I'm trying to do is to create a new array and each element of the new array contains the sum of all the values of the same index of arrays inside the big array.

'''

```
array = [[1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5], [1, 2, 3, 4, 5]] 
(length of array inside =5)
new = [4,8,12,16,20]
```

'''
But the length of the arrays inside the big array is identical but can be flexible

Comment: is this an array or a list?

Comment: it's an array, not a list

Comment: `[sum(i) for i in zip(*array)]` or `list(map(sum, zip(*array)))`

Comment: olvin// i love you

Comment: @jpark and I love when you search for answer before posting new ;-)

Comment: @OlvinRoght if you don't mind, can i ask one more question? if that "array" is one of the array inside a bigger array. for ex, bigger_array = [array, array, ....]. how can i classify smallest arrays in the same index

Comment: @jpark, could you give an example?

Comment: @OlvinRoght for example, array = [[a,b,c,d,e], [1,2,3,4,5], [6,7,8,9,0]]// bigger_array = [array, array, array] // what i want is new_array[0] = [[a,b,c,d,e],[a,b,c,d,e],[a,b,c,d,e]] // new_array[1] = [[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5],[1,2,3,4,5]] // new_array[2] = [ [6,7,8,9,0], [6,7,8,9,0], [6,7,8,9,0]]

Comment: @jpark, `new_array = [[ar[:] for _ in range(len(array))] for ar in array]`?

Comment: @OlvinRoght i dont think so unfortunately. i think i should give another example for better understanding. // array = [[a,b,c,d,e], [f, g, h, i, j], [k, l, m, n, o], [1,2,3,4,5], [6,7,8,9,0]] // bigger_array = [array, array, array]. the length of new array should be changed depends on the length of "array", and in each "new array" should contain all the same index of array of "array" . new_array[0] = [[a,b,c,d,e], [a,b,c,d,e], [a,b,c,d,e]] ....new_array[4] = [[6,7,8,9,0], [6,7,8,9,0], [6,7,8,9,0]]

Comment: @jpark, change `range(len(array))` to `range(3)`

Comment: @OlvinRoght it didnt solve. can i ask what ar[:] and underscore between for and in do?

Comment: @jpark, better ask separate question with details, comments is not for this.

Comment: @OlvinRoght website won't allow me. i will try to work on with what you have given me. i really appreciate for your help. it drove me crazy for keep using for loops for lots of arrays

Answer (score 0):

You have two solutions to it. You can use sum for every "little array" with it :

```
array = [sum([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]), sum([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]), sum([1, 2, 3, 4, 5]), sum([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])]
```

The other solutions is create variables lists and use append when you like.

```
array_one=sum([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
array_two=sum([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
array_total=[]
array_total.append(array_one)
array_total.append(array_two)
```

If you want the sum of this arrray_total you can use `sum(array_total)` too

Comment: ...What is this?

Comment: You can create a function too, where you can add every list you want to add and use sum.

Comment: What´s your question?

Comment: How does this answer related to question?

Comment: This basic form to get your answer

Comment: Well, the task is to sum all elements of inner lists by index, so it will sum first element of each inner list and store result into a first element of result list, then it should sum second element of each inner list and store result into a second element, and so on. Your code just sum all elements of each inner list.

Comment: @RaphaelMoralPiazera yea what Olvin showed is correct for what I wanted. but still thanks for ur answer, i learn something new from you too

Comment: Thank you guys too, I learn something new too